# Python valid values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to fix older code someone wrote years ago using python. I believe the "\d\d\d\d" refers to the number of text characters, and 0-9A-Z limits the type of input but I can't find any documentation on this.

```
idTypes = {"PFI":"\d\d\d\d",
       "VA HOSPITAL ID":"V\d\d\d",
       "CERTIFICATION NUMBER":"\d\d\d-[A-Z]-\d\d\d",
       "MORTUARY FIRM ID":"[0-9]",
       "HEALTH DEPARTMENT ID":"[0-9]",
       "NYSDOH OFFICE ID":"[0-9]",
       "ACF ID":"AF\d\d\d\d",
   "GENERIC NUMBER ID":"[0-9]",
       "GENERIC ID":"[A-Za-z0-9]",
       "OASAS FAC":"[0-9]",
       "OMH PSYCH CTR":"[0-9A-Z]"}
```

Like the PFI values seem to be limited to 4 numeric digits in a string field, so 12345 doesn't work later in the code but 1234 does. Adding another \d doesn't appear to be the answer.

Comment: There's no `\d` escape in Python.

Comment: `\d` escapes unicode strings in the python 're' regular expression library.

Comment: In a regular expression, "\d" means "one numeric character" ("d" standing for "digit").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are, apparently, regular expressions used to validate inputs. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Without seeing the code that **uses** these values it is impossible to say more.

Comment: I guess it would have been easier if I knew they were regular expressions to find the documentation. The comments and links helped me understand what they were doing. Thanks for the quick comments an answer.

Comment: To elaborate this, \d means 'digit' in regular expression for 1 numeric character. There's no use declaring it outside regex functions.